# Using decorators to solve mathematical equations in Python (Past Paper Qs)

Tags: python, function, math, decorator, modulo

I have been asked to find the modulo 37 (%37) of a function.

> Ensure that your function returns an integer between 0 and 36.
>   Assume that all arguments are integers between 0 and 36.
>   Write a decorator `@normalize_37` that does just that. I.e. if 'bar' is a function, then the decorated function will have all its arguments reduced modulo 37 and its return value reduced modulo 37.

Find:

```
@normalize_37
def add(x,y):
     return x+y
print(add(45,67))
#where the answer is 1.

@normalize_37
 def bar(n):
     if n >= 37 or n <= -1:
         raise ValueError
     else:
         return n
print(bar(123))
#where the answer is 12
```

So far I have came up with this for the first bit from looking up decorators online:

```
import math

def document(f):
    def wrap(x,y):
        print("I am going to find modulo 37 of", x,y)
        f(x,y)
    return wrap

@document
def add(x,y):
    print(add(x,y)%37)

add(45,67)
```

but it isn't working for me and when I run it, it just repeats the "I am going to find modulo 37 of" bit over and over again.

Comment: ... you call `f(x, y)` but you don't actually modulo it or return the result.

Answer (score 3):

The specific form requested would be

```
def normalize_37(fn):              # the decorator
    def inner(x, y):               # the new decorated function
        return fn(x, y) % 37
    return inner

@normalize_37
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

add(45, 67)    # returns 112 % 37 == 1
```

but we can generalize one step further,

```
def normalize(n):                  # make a decorator!
    def decorator(fn):             # the decorator
        def inner(*args):          # the new decorated function
            return fn(*args) % n
        return inner
    return decorator

@normalize(37)
def add(*args):
    return sum(args)

add(45, 67)    # returns 112 % 37 == 1
```

**Edit:** ok, I missed the bit about reducing the arguments as well. So it becomes

```
def normalize(n):                  # make a decorator!
    def decorator(fn):             # the decorator
        def inner(*args):          # the new decorated function
            return fn(*(arg % n for arg in args)) % n
        return inner
    return decorator

@normalize(37)
def add(*args):
    return sum(args)

add(45, 67)    # returns ((45 % 37) + (67 % 37)) % 37 == 1
```

or in the simpler form,

```
def normalize_37(fn):              # the decorator
    def inner(x, y):               # the new decorated function
        return fn(x % 37, y % 37) % 37
    return inner
```

Comment: Well, check his `bar` example as well.